# Visible select element with "opacity: 0" in Opera since version 12

Tags: html, css, opera

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mRBsX/3/).
In Opera since 12th version select is visible in spite of "opacity: 0"! In version 11.x it was ok. In other browsers it looks ok.

Also, I made simple demo without complex css, where was "opacity 0"-select -- it was actually transparent! Something is wrong with my styles, I could not find what is.

Comment: i have opera 11 and it works i will now update to see the demo on version 12

Answer (score 1):

to solve this i added new style

```
 .selectnewstyle
            {
                position: relative;
                left: -160px;
                opacity: 0;

                width: 160px;
                padding: 4px 4px;
            }
```

and applied it to the select

```
<select class="selectnewstyle" id="catid" name="catid">
```

**this must be a compatibility issues how each different browser brain works**

here is the modified demo

[demo on opera 12 working](http://jsfiddle.net/sssonline2/MAn29/1/)

**UPDATE**

suprisingly the solution was to add a space between div and the select tags and i dont know why is it just jsfiddle bug ; see the demo above

Comment: In fact extra style does nothing. Solution is space character between <input ...> and <select ...> as in your demo. I have no idea why.

Comment: jsfiddle does not have an influence, I tested via test.html file locally.

Answer (score 1):

You also can use another CSS rule:

```
visibility: [visible | hidden]
```

It works almost like opacity. The only difference is how it spells with audio browsers. But visual rendering is the same as `opacity` rule has.

Comment: A good idea. I did not tried coz the question is not actual for me now. Opera 12 has gone.

Comment: Well, sometimes this bug is of current interest. It depends on a situation. If users quantity of Opera 12 is quite big, then you have no choice :) Like I have now. I hope Opera will fade away ASAP